# How can I delete owl imports?

Tags: owl, ontology, owl-api

For example, I have imported ontology x.owl and y.owl into z.owl. I want to remove x.owl after some reasoning. How can I do this using the owl api?

Comment: `man.applyChange(new RemoveImport(o, m.getOWLDataFactory().getOWLImportsDeclaration(IRI.create("http://domain.for.import.ontology/importedontology"))));`

Comment: The comment above should be the full answer. For context, all changes to an ontology go through either an Add or a Remove object (AddAxiom, RemoveAxiom, AddImport, RemoveImport). Also note that, after changing the imports, it might be necessary to flush the reasoner for it to see the changes).